# Eclipse, Java, external jar and problem with autocompletion

Tags: java, eclipse

I used to work with C# in Visual Studio. When I added an external library .Net Framework, when entering class or interface names in the code editor, I was always offered names from the connected library. Now I'm using Eclipse and I don't understand why, after added an external jar, my code editor doesn't offer autocompletion of names?

For the parameter: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Auto activation triggers for java
Setting the value: .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

In my maven project, I connect dependencies to libraries:
jna-5.13.0.jar
jna-platform-5.13.0.jar
Right-click on the project -> Maven -> Update project
Libraries were automatically added to the project via "Maven Dependencies"

Why when I enter the text "import com.sun." I don't have the prompt "import com.sun.jna"?
I press ctrl+space and see the message "No Default Proposals"...

I tried to add libraries directly!

Copying libraries:
jna-5.13.0.jar
jna-platform-5.13.0.jar
To the project/src directory

Right-click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries
I delete Maven Dependencies and manually add a jar using "Add JARs ..."

After my actions, the problem remained, the autocompletion of the code does not offer me "import com.sun.jna".
If I enter a class name from a connected library (for example, Pointer), I am not prompted to autocomplete it or import "import com.sun.jnaPointer".

For the test, I connect "import com.sun.jna.Pointer;".
When entering "Pointe", I am offered autocompletion only from the wrong libraries "java.awt", "java.lang", "java.util".
Why is the class name from "import com.sun.jna.Pointer" not suggested?

Why does it work for him, but it doesn't work for me? Between 5:30 and 6:00 [How to solve problems while importing classes from external jars in Eclipse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndJxdZu0nAw&t=330s)

Comment: `com.sun.*` are blocked/filtered by default because there are not public API, so better don't use it. You can change this in the preferences _Java > Appearance > Type Filters_ (not recommended!).

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been found! Thanks @howlger

"`com.sun.*` is blocked/filtered by default because it is not public API, so better not to use it. You can change this in the preferences Java > Appearance > Type Filters (not recommended!)"